# How to properly implement IHydratable interface in DNN?

Tags: interface, dotnetnuke, dotnetnuke-5

After upgrading to [DNN 5.5.0](http://dotnetnuke.codeplex.com/releases/view/50755) we had to implement `IHydratable` on all of our business objects.

This idea seemed like a good way to go at first, but after playing with `IHydratable` I'm not so sure any more.

**There are two possibilities:**

1. I'm doing it wrong
2. `IHydratable` forces you to use `select *` construct an all your queries

**The business case:**

- My first sproc returns the `BgId` and `BgShortDesc`
- My second sproc returns `BgId` and `BgReportedUser`

**My `IHydratable` is implemented as show below:**

```cs
public class Bug : IHydratable
{ 
  public int BgId { get; set; }
  public string BgShortDesc { get; set; }
  public int BgReportedUser { get; set; }
  public DateTime BgReportedDate { get; set; }

  public Bug() { }

  public int KeyID
  {
    get { return BgId; }
    set { BgId = value; }
  }

  public void Fill(IDataReader dr)
  {
    BgId = Convert.ToInt32(Null.SetNull(dr["BgId"], BgId));
    BgShortDesc = Convert.ToString(Null.SetNull(dr["BgShortDesc"], BgShortDesc));
    BgReportedUser = Convert.ToInt32(Null.SetNull(dr["BgReportedUser"], BgReportedUser));
    BgReportedDate = Convert.ToDateTime(Null.SetNull(dr["BgReportedDate"], BgReportedDate));
  }
}
```

The fill method will throw an `IndexOutOfRangeException` on any of the above sprocs, since not all the fields get returned with `IDataReader`.

The easy way around the problem is to use `select *` in all of the sprocs, but that's not a good practice.

**What's the PROPER way of implementing `IHydratable` in this scenario?**

***P.S.*** keep in mind that my example is oversimplified to get the point across.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got a feasible answer to this on [another forum](http://dnnqna.com/questions/126/how-to-properly-implement-ihydratable-interface-in-dnn)

Here's the suggestion:

```
    public void Fill(IDataReader dr)
    {
            if (dr.ColumnExists("BgId"))
            {
              BgId = Convert.ToInt32(Null.SetNull(dr["BgId"], BgId));
            }
            //do the above for all the properties
    }
```

**EDIT:**

Found a better way of doing this by writing an extension method on IDataReader with the help of these 2 answers on SO ([@JamesEggers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1206596/checking-to-see-if-a-column-exists-in-a-data-reader/1213409#1213409) and [@Chad Grant](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/373230/check-for-column-name-in-a-sqldatareader-object/813741#813741))

```
    /// <summary>
    /// Check if the column exists in the datareader before accessing its value
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="reader">DataReader</param>
    /// <param name="columnName">Column name</param>
    /// <returns>True if column exists, false if not</returns>
    public static bool ColumnExists(this IDataReader reader, string columnName)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < reader.FieldCount; i++)
        {
            if (reader.GetName(i).Equals(columnName, StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase))
            {
                return true;
            }
        }

        return false;
    }
```